# AOS Animation in one page web site

Tags: javascript, html, aos.js

Hey is it possible to make the elements activate only 1 time when the page loaded? So animation will not play all the time you scroll up and down, but only the one first time you do it?

contant

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: Hello! Could you please provide more information about what libraries or techniques you are using? Maybe share a bit of the specific critical code you are trying to improve? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
AOS.init({
    once: true,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<div class="mx-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-once=“true”>
  Demo text
</div
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO. Nice to have you here. Please check the documentation here https://github.com/michalsnik/aos. In the object you provide to the AOS library to initialize the animation, you can specify a property called `once` to set whether the animation would run once or not.